# How to invoke/start rake task along with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usually, I'll do some rake task to generate some files after starting the rails server. Instead of doing this repeatedly is there any option to patch/hook 'rails s' command to execute/invoke rake task?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of patching, just wrap it. Create a new script file that will perform what you have to perform, then starts the rails server.

When you have to start the server, start your file instead of calling the Rails server directly.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a script to create the files you need is one way to achieve your desired outcome. Maybe more portable or deployment-friendly way could be 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#running-code-before-rails